# Gigya Logout Issue

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, logout, gigya

I am implementing gigya to authorise users from facebook, twitter, linkedin and gmail. Everthing works great as I need very little information. I am using socialize logout to logout users, but It does not work as desired, It logs out of the hosted site but not the service provider.

Is there any option that I might have overlooked that logs out users from the service providers? I using facebook, twitter, linkedin and google.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick,

You can do this for Facebook by configuring a domain alias (CNAME):

http://wiki.gigya.com/035_Socialize_Setup/020_Facebook_Settings

This only applies to Facebook. For other service providers (twitter, google, etc), users will remain logged in.

I suspect the functionality will evolve as this issue receives more attention. For now, perhaps your site logout process should remind users that they're still logged in to (xyz) provider.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, so my comments are in addition to his.

The behavior you see is correct.  Gigya is essentially a proxy for user connectivity and, therefore, represents a session to the social network for the site through which the user connected.  However, the session with the social network provider is distinct as well, so Gigya does not presume that it owns the user's absolute social connection.  As a best practice, Gigya recommends that your site/application alert the user to sign out from each network to which they are connected.

Although facebook provides a mechanism for logging the user out from facebook (as described in the prior answer), other social network connections should be terminated by the user.  This is especially important for public/shared computers.  To provide additional integrity Gigya also provides a setting called 'sessionExpiration' for connect/login that determines the longevity of the session.

Comment: I think developers and many users would have liked a choice to terminate the connection with a single click.